# how to convert a json with metadata or lists to a proper csv rows and header format using python?

Tags: python, json, csv

my sample json:

```
               {
             "data":[
                   {
               "filter":"tags",
                "cost":1234,
              "values":[
               {
              "count":13,
             "subvalues":[
                {
                  "count":1,
                 "subvalue":"goat",
                 "cost":227.576
                 },
                  "storage":[
                    {
                "resource_id":"1234343413",
              "cost":25.047,
                 "running_hours %":61.52777777777778,
               "created_in":"asd ",
                 "account_name":null,
                    "service":"csdsae",
                    etcc...
```

and i want to convert this in proper headers and columns using python

my code is as below :

```
import json
import csv
f = open('cost_drilldown_data.json')

data = json.loads(f)

s=csv.writer(open('test1.csv','w'))
count = 0
for item in data:
    f.writerow(item)

    if count == 0:
        header = item.keys()
        s.writerow(header)
        count += 1

    s.writerow(item.values())
s.close()
```

but i am getting error like :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\csvtry2.py", 
                 line 9, in <module>
    data = json.loads(f)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: You want `json.load` rather than `json.loads`. The former parses the contents of a file. The latter expects (as the error message says) a string or buffer.

Comment: after changing to json.load now i am getting different error with writerow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\csvtry2.py", line 15, in <module>
    f.writerow(item)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writerow'

Comment: Maybe you meant `s.writerow`?

Comment: ok changed 
now 
  File "C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\csvtry2.py",
    header = item.keys()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'

getting error with keys

Comment: You probably want `for item in data["data"]`. Just try printing out `item` to see what you're getting now. In general, try carefully reading your error messages and then debugging your program yourself.

Comment: no i tried for item in data:
     s.writerow(item)
if count == 0:
                        header = item

                        s.writerow(header)

                        count += 1

                        s.writerow(item)
But it is just printing the string separately eg d a t a

Ok done now
    s.writerow(item)
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: @smarx now i am getting   File "C:\Python27\robotscripts\A
    s.writerow(item)
_csv.Error: sequence expected
Please correct me here

Comment: No. Try debugging your own code.